# Bluetooth only Connection with Nearby-Communication

Tags: android, bluetooth, google-nearby

I'm wondering if it's possible to have a Bluetooth connection only in Googles Nearby-Connections API.
The problem is, if i have a running hotspot for my notebook, google Nearby will cut off the connection.
If I use the connections-activity from github, it will raise a hotspot after the acceptConnection() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change from 'Strategy.P2P_STAR' to 'Strategy.P2P_CLUSTER'.

STAR uses hotspots and is generally more disruptive but has higher bandwidth as a result. CLUSTER will only ever use non-disruptive mediums.